# Unable to install Oh-my-posh

Tags: windows-10, powershell, oh-my-zsh

I have been following the tutorial in https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/windows so I can get my nice **Oh-My-Posh** as I've always had. They seem to have changed from installing a module to a different way of installing using `winget`.

I follow the tutorial and I get a success message indicating that everything went fine. But when I close the prompt and open a new one, everything stays the same. I cannot do a `Get-PoshThemes` because PowerShell does not recognize the CmdLet but I know Oh-My-Posh is installed cause if I try to uninstall it via `winget`, the PC recognizes the command and performs the uninstallation process.

Does anyone have any insight in how to sucessfully proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/discussions/2425) with the help of Jan, the creator of Oh My Posh.

Basically, you need to add the init command to your `$PROFILE` file. This profile file is basically a `powershell_profile.ps1` file.

Inside of your `$PROFILE` file, you would add something along the lines of:

```
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config 'fullPathTo/the_theme_you_want.json' | Invoke-Expression
```

And yes, forward slashes, for some reason.

This will initiate ***oh-my-posh*** when you start a ***PowerShell* prompt** by default.

I was lacking the init line since I was (wrongly) understanding that this command was a one-time command that you would run and it would dump the config into the `$PROFILE` file by itself.